# Django filter not passing value through url

Tags: django, filtering

I've been following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vU0VeFN-abU, but when I try to pass a value through the form no value appears after the '?' Do I have a typo somewhere?

When I enter `C34` what I should get in the url is: `/?C34`

Instead I just get: `/?`

My code:

```
#Urls.py
path('', SampleFliterView, name='SampleFliterView'),

#views.py
def SampleFliterView(request):
    qs = Sample.objects.all()
    sample_number_query = request.GET.get('sample_number')
    container_name_query = request.GET.get('container_name')

    if container_name_query != '' and container_name_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(sample_number__icontains=container_name_query)

    context = {
        'queryset': qs
    }
    return render(request, "container/filter.html", context)

#html template
<form class="" action="." method="GET">

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border " type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Sample Number" name="sample_number"/>
        <span class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border " type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Container Name" name="container_name"/>
        <span class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `name=""` in input twice. Remove blank ones and it would work as expected